# dup of anonymous pipe instead of stdout and passing arguments through it

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, pipe

The issuse:
we create 2 pipes, the father forks and creates a child, pasing it both of the pipes.
the father sends info through his pipe to the kid.
the kid after reciving it should send it back.
the kid should send it back through out the stdout using the library functions:
the problem is in this section:

the parent expects output from child using read :

```
//READ FOR INT
            read(pipe_child_to_father[0], &number_recived, sizeof(int));
            printf("number recived: %d \n", number_recived);
```

the child sends iput using either printf and fflush or write
I commented above each one which works and which dont

```
//---------------------------------SECTION WITH PROBLEM ------------------------
        //-------------------WITH INTS
        //WORKS
        write(STDOUT_FILENO,&number, sizeof(int)); 
        
        //NOT WORKING !!! sends wrong input
        printf("%d",number); 
        fflush(stdout);
        
        //NOT WORKING !! gets stuck waiting for input
        //printf("%d",number); 
        
        //NOT WORKING !!! sends wrong input
        fprintf(stdout, "%d", number);  
        fflush(stdout);
```

I am pasting the full code as well at the buttom.

the output i get:
if the kid using printf to send data to the father(using fflush to clear buffer) - the numbers should be the same!:

```
number sent :34461 
number recived: 909194548 
number sent :168284 
number recived: 842348086 
number sent :138440 
number recived: 909457719 
number sent :141832 
number recived: 909193265
```

if i dont use fflush - the father gets stuck waiting for input....

few notes:

1. This thread is not about asking help in solving hw.
2. This problem was stumbled on part of the assigment, I know there are things like message ques and named pipes that might be better for this kind of job, but we should only use named pipes.

the full code if some one wants to copy paste it:

> ```
> #include <stdlib.h> //for exit_succes
> #include <stdio.h> // for prints
> #include <unistd.h> //sleep for debug
> #include <sys/types.h> // for pid_t
> #include <errno.h>     //for perror
> #include <signal.h>    //for signal
> #include <time.h>
>
> #define true  1
> #define false 0
> #define MAX_NUMBERS 2000
> #define MAX_RND 200000
> #define FATHER_RUNS 50
>
>
>
> int iteri_search( int numbers[], int number);
> void father_process();
> void init_array(int array[]);
> void kid(int array[], int pipe_recive[], int pipe_transmit[]);
> void get_data(int pipe_father_to_bianry[], int pipe_binary_to_father[]);
>
>
> int main (){
>   
>   father_process();
>
>
>   
>   exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
> }
>
>
> void father_process(){
>   
>   pid_t pid;
>   
>   
>   
>   //setting array
>   int array[MAX_NUMBERS];
>   
>   //initializing it
>   init_array(array);
>       
>   //setting pipes 
>   int pipe_father_to_child[2];
>   int pipe_child_to_father[2];
>   
>   //Open all pipes
>   if(pipe(pipe_father_to_child) == -1)
>   {
>       perror("Error");
>       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
>   }
>   
>   if(pipe(pipe_child_to_father) == -1)
>   {
>       perror("Error");
>       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
>   }   
>   pid = fork();
>       
>       //first kid
>   
>   if(pid == 0)
>   {
>       kid(array,pipe_father_to_child, pipe_child_to_father);
>   }
>       
>       
>
>   
>   ///close unwanted pipes for father
>   close(pipe_child_to_father[1]);
>   close(pipe_father_to_child[0]);
>
>   
>   get_data(pipe_father_to_child, pipe_child_to_father);
>   
>   
>   
> }
>
>
> void get_data(int pipe_father_to_child[], int pipe_child_to_father[]){
>   
>   int index_of_run = 0;
>   int number_recived = 0;
>   double double_recived =0;
>
>   
>   while(index_of_run < FATHER_RUNS){
>       
>
>       int number = rand()%MAX_RND;    
>       
>       write(pipe_father_to_child[1], &number, sizeof(int));
>       printf("number sent :%d \n", number);
>       
>       
>       //SENDING THE INPUT ------------------------ THE PROBLEMATIC PART
>       //READ FOR INT
>       read(pipe_child_to_father[0], &number_recived, sizeof(int));
>       printf("number recived: %d \n", number_recived);
>       
>       ++index_of_run;
>   }
> }
>
>
>
> void kid(int array[], int pipe_recive[], int pipe_transmit[]){
>   
>   //will mesure time
>
>   
>   //close unwanted pipes
>   close (pipe_recive[1]);
>   close (pipe_transmit[0]);
>   
>
>   dup2(pipe_transmit[1],STDOUT_FILENO);
>
>   int number = 0;
>   
>   int index =0;
>   
>   while(index < 50)
>   {
>       //get number from father
>       read(pipe_recive[0], &number, sizeof(int));
>   
>       // turn on clock
>       
>       //---------------------------------SECTION WITH PROBLEM ------------------------
>       
>       //WORKS - correct output
>       //write(STDOUT_FILENO,&number, sizeof(int)); 
>       
>       //NOT WORKING !!! sends wrong input as explained above
>       //printf("%d",number); 
>       //fflush(stdout);
>       
>       //NOT WORKING !! gets stuck waiting for input
>       //printf("%d",number); 
>       
>       //NOT WORKING !!! sends wrong input as explained with printf
>       //fprintf(stdout, "%d", number);    
>       //fflush(stdout);
>       
>       
>       
>       ++index;
>
>   }
>   
>   exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
>   
> }
>
>
> //initializing array with values
> void init_array(int array[]){
>   srand(17);
>   int index;
>   for(index = 0; index < MAX_NUMBERS; ++index){
>       array[index] = rand();
>   }
>   
> }
> ```

Comment: Processes are not gendered.  Rather than "father", it is "parent".  Always.

Comment: You're not checking the values returned by any of the `read`s or `write`s.  Also, you've commented out large sections of the code.  Comments like "WORKS" or "NOT WORKING" are not particularly descriptive.  Which code exactly did what?  Are we supposed to guess which comments should be undone?

Comment: After `dup2(x,y)`, you typically do `close(x)` to avoid having 2 copies of the descriptor.

Comment: It seems that the root of your question is the difference between `write(1, &number, sizeof number)` and `printf("%d", number)`.  But I'm not sure what "NOT WORKING !!! sends wrong input" actually means.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I edited the question. I hope its more clear now. please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there are many other issues, but certainly you need to deal with this:

```
char * buff = NULL;
...
read(pipe_child_to_father[0], &buff, sizeof(buff));
```

You are not writing an address through the pipe.  Since you are trying to read a value generated by a printf format string of %d, you almost certainly want something like:

```
char buf[32];
...
rc = read(pipe_child_to_parent[0], buf, sizeof buf);
```

Comment: is using:
`read(pipe_child_to_father[0], &number_recived, sizeof(int));`
not enougth?
it should read out the size of int from the input.

Comment: If you have used "%d" to print the integer as a string, then values larger than 9999 will not fit in a 4 byte value.  If integers are 8 bytes, then you'll have trouble with values larger than 99999999.  But if you read a string and try to treat it as an int, you will get unexpected output.

Comment: oh i think i get it now.
so the `printf` converts it to str, thats why it get recived as str.
so the only way is either to recive at as string and atoi  to integer or to send it through the write command.